# itunes connect / Testflight app always show old version (even if we upload a new one to testflight)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

we are scratching our heads,

we worked with the new testflight/ itunes connect and were able to submit builds for internal users.
somehow, it stopped working and it always goes to an old build when we release.

**under prereleases, we see all versions (1.0.7, 1.0.7.1 -> 1.0.7.7)** - all other versions are inactive. 
each time we release to testflight, relevant internal users gets an email (invited to use the latest build) - but when we open it via testflight -it always lets us to install 1.0.7.3).

i've asked apple about it but they haven't answered for like a week and a half.

anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I'm also having this problem.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485930/apple-testflight-no-longer-allows-me-release-new-builds-to-external-testers#comment45297989_28485930

Comment: @sylvanaar yes this is a bug also in their forums. just do what the solution proposes.

Comment: @ArielB for me the solution does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i was able to resolve this - needed to click and disable "TestFlight beta testing" and then enabling it again.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  After toggling it off and back on everyone got push notifications for the latest versions.

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: what do you see when you enable it again in the list of builds? (30 days left thingy?) or still nothing?

Comment: As of May 23 bug still exists :)

Comment: $179billion in the bank and we have to put up with this

Comment: i also remove my testers and add them again using the on/off checkbox

Comment: @jenson-button-event try to add another tester and see if it works?
the disable/enable should solve this.
if you manager to solve it in another way, people will surely be glad to see the solution here aswell

Comment: bug still exists and the work around isnt working anymore

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to go to -All users in the left menu of Testflight in Appstore connect and delete the user there. Then go to the disired build and add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I had a similar issue with my Testflight always loading an old build and this was due to the way I previously wrote the version.

The previous version was 0.58 and my newest build was 0.7. For some reason, Testflight would only recognize 0.7 as the newest version if it was written as 0.70. It seems to an annoying bug in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this problem in 2021:

1. Go to the tab testflight (inside appstoreconnect.apple.com)
2. Click individual testers
3. Remove them one by one
4. Add them again

voila!