# Apple TestFlight No Longer Allows Me Release New Builds To External Testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an application in iTunes Connect configured for TestFlight beta testing. Before our first application release we were able to invite external testers, but once we submitted the first version of our application for review the option to submit the app for beta test review went away, and our app was only testable by internal testers.

Now that our app was approved we want to allow external testers to test a new version of our app, but the option to allow external testers never appears.

[image: Sceeenshot From iTunes Connect]

Is there something I need to do to allow me to beta test this new version.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't beta test a released version. So add version 1.1 and beta test that.

Comment: We never released 1.0.2, but we did do a build early on that we labeled 1.0.2. We released 1.0.1 and 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple pushed a fix to TestFlight that resolved this issue for us on 3/12/2015

Answer (score 0):

Remember to login using an account with the Legal, Admin, or App Manager role. (More info on user roles [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24).)