# iTunes Connect - Beta App Review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, testflight

I am trying to submit our app for Beta App Review, and we used to see a button pop up immediately under External such as `Submit for Beta App Review`.

It's not showing up anymore. Any thoughts on how this can be fixed? 
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, mine still does. However, click on your build and see if you have provided any test build's information yet, I think it's required.

Comment: I have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485930/apple-testflight-no-longer-allows-me-release-new-builds-to-external-testers#comment45297989_28485930

Comment: I have a support request open with apple. I couldn't find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Still a problem :0 God! Apple....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

You necessarily don't have to resubmit for beta app review each time after your app has been approved once for beta test flight:

> A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

So if it's not a substantial change of features, your app will be pushed to testers immediately

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

EDIT:

You also have to have a different binary uploaded

Comment: But... everytim I submit a new binary, I get pushed into the beta review queue?